# webview in android

Tags: java, android

i was working on webview following the link http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html and it is working fine but the problem is i cant view the whole page i mean that it is horizontally not scrollable.

how can i view the whole page by scrolling both horizontally and vertically?

Activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class HelloWebView extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the webview defined in your xml, you can do the following:

```
android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
```

Comment: Actually, that would be `android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```